# Matching a pattern n times using regex

Tags: .net, regex

I've been writing a file parser and in the parser I parse each line using a regular expression, if it matches then I parse out the data.

I should admit now, my regex knowledge is basic at best......

So I have a line that looks like this:

```
( -3456 -3104 344 -24 -10 1 0 0 ) ( -3456 -2976 344 -23 -10 1 0 0 ) ( -3456 -2976 312 -23 -9 1 0 0 )
```

8 floating point values (above in brackets, repeated n times (3 above, but could me more or fewer).

I tried this:

```
\( (.*?) \)
```

Which parsed out the content of the brackets (which I then parsed out using another regex), but that also matched lines like this:

```
/* iap 0 */ 4 5 1 ( 176 -1272 120 ) ( 176 -1272 264 ) ( 176 -1416 264 ) ( 176 -1416 120 )
```

Which I didn't want it to. I guess this is because I don't specify the start `^`

But if I do I only seem to get the 1st set of brackets...

```
^\( (.*?) \)
```

I've been looking at this for hours, going in circles, but struggling to find what I'm after - pointers/help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick to distinguish your example:

```
^(\([0-9. -]+\) *)+$
```

It's looking for one or more set of parentheses (brackets) with only numbers, spaces, hyphens (minus signs), and decimal points inside. It also allows whitespace between the sets, and requires that they take up the whole line. If you need it to specifically match only sets of eight numbers, that will look a bit different.

Comment: This only seems to capture the middle set of brackets for me? I end up with 2 groups - 1 for everything and 1 for the middle set.

Comment: I managed to dig deeper and this works if I walk the matches/groups/captures correctly. I've marked Ahmad's answer as helpful due to the volume of clear concise information in there!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict the pattern to matching eight digits try the following pattern:

```
string pattern = @"\(\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b\s*){8}\)";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

You can access the captured values in the group rather than use a second regex to grab the numbers. That would look like this:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match: " + m.Value);
    foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
    {
        foreach (Capture c in g.Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Bear in mind that the first item in the capture group represents the entire match, so if you don't need it you can skip it (use a for loop and an index starting at 1).

Breakdown of the pattern:

- `\(\s*`: literal `(` and whitespace (any number of repetitions)
- `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`: optional negative symbol, one or more numbers, and an optional decimal point followed by numbers (the latter part is in a non-capturing group since it's within `(?: ...)`
- `\b\s*`: word boundary to ensure matching ends after each digit, followed by zero or more whitespace characters
- the last two parts of the pattern are in a capture group since they are enclosed within parentheses
- `{8}`: repeated exactly 8 times
- `\)`: literal `)`

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same problem as mine - the second example matches if that has a set of brackets with 8 numbers in, whereas it shouldnt do (it has part of the pattern, but doesnt exclusively follow the pattern).